# ConseilJS TezosContractIntrospector.generateEntryPointsFromAddress `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, error, javascript, conseil

Trying to retrieve contract entry points using the [TezosContractIntrospector](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/master/src/chain/tezos/TezosContractIntrospector.ts#L18)

The following code:

```
async function entry_points(){
  const server={
    url:'https://conseil-dev.cryptonomic-infra.tech:443',
    apiKey:'foo',
    network:'babylonnet
  };
  const contractAddress='KT1WRUe3csC1jiThN9KUtaji2bd412upfn1E';
  const result=await conseiljs.TezosContractIntrospector.generateEntryPointsFromAddress(
    server,
    server['network'],
    contractAddress
  );
}
```

attempts to interact with the deployed contract from a [medium post](https://medium.com/the-cryptonomic-aperiodical/simplified-contract-interactions-on-tezos-39c67bdeeffc) but results in the error:

```
conseiljs.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  at Object.<anonymous> (conseiljs.min.js:2)
  at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
  at o (conseiljs.min.js:2)
```

If `typeof` is used:

```
console.log(typeof(
  conseiljs.TezosContractIntrospector.generateEntryPointsFromAddress(
    server,
    server['network'],
    contractAddress
  )
);
```

it is of type `object` but I am unsure how to handle it.

I wish to find the entry points of a contract to use it to [sendContractInvocationOperation](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/f189bc1d8aafa33db2d5beb587711faadfb51e50/src/chain/tezos/TezosNodeWriter.ts#L515)

**Any help is much appreciated**

Comment: Fyi not sure abt conseiljs but entry points are available here https://smartpy.io/test2/explore.html?address=KT1WRUe3csC1jiThN9KUtaji2bd412upfn1E

Comment: Thanks for this @Ezy. Could you provide any more information about doing this? I followed your link but I'm not sure what I am looking at. I was hoping to return Michelson for use in the function [sendContractInvocationOperation](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/master/src/chain/tezos/TezosNodeWriter.ts) which requires both an `entry point` and `parameters`. Where would I find this information via your linked page? Thanks

Comment: If you open https://smartpy.io/dev/explore.html?address=KT1WRUe3csC1jiThN9KUtaji2bd412upfn1E (same as test2 but will be supported longer as it is SmartPy's official dev release and test2 was only used for this release) you can look at the bottom of the page. You'll see three tabs including Parameter Type.

Bad news: this contract has two annoying features:
- it has no annotation so you have to determine on your own what does what
- it has a little 'do' extra entry point which was used as an automatic conversion in Babylon for removed operations. I think ConseilJS fails on those.

Comment: Hi @FFF, I don't suppose you could provide any insight into how that can be used for the [ConseilJS](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/master/src/chain/tezos/TezosNodeWriter.ts) function? I made a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fDYQFjAL) that includes the content from the parameter tab you linked. Thanks

Comment: @macourtney7, I must admit that I simply don't know if you can use the introspector of ConseilJS on these contracts.

Comment: No problem, @FFF. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function preprocesses input and eventually passes to [generateEntryPointsFromParams](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS/blob/84cf23bd2eabe13fc7f6221bc6807844ef2a0587/src/chain/tezos/TezosContractIntrospector.ts)

Due to the issues encountered with generateEntryPointsFromAddress I used the following workaround:

```
async function foo(contract_params){
  const entry_points=await 
    conseiljs.TezosContractIntrospector.generateEntryPointsFromParams(contract_params);
  console.table(entry_points);
}
```

This will display the entry points. Which is the desired results.

Parameters can usually be easily retrieved (for example, from an online explorer).